Column sorting in access with Letter and number
I am having issues sorting my database it as gotten issues when i had to add items.  It starts with R01 and runs to R134.  When it gets to R10 it follows with R100,R101,R102 til it gets to R11 then it goes to R110 AND SO AND SO ON.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong its driving me nuts
Tried sorting, changing the expressions

Ok so you have a few choices.  Some may or may not be possible, depending on your particular situation.
The issue stems from the way text and numbers are sorted. As a general guideline, when you have numbers represented as text (usually due to leading 0s), you just need to figure out the biggest number you will ever have and stick on enough leading 0s to be sure that all entries are the same length. Or, in your case, have enough 0s between the letters and numbers so all entries are the same length.  Here are my suggestions.

Is there any way to start at R001 instead of R01? If so, this is probably the best way to go, as the current situation seems like the data has an inherent issue already.  If you can, change the data.

Can you add another field that takes the R01-R99 and makes them R001-R099?  Then just sort on that field.  If you can't change the data, then adding a key field could work. It would even be easier to just save the numeric part of the field in the new key field. R01 becomes 1, R99 becomes 99, R102 becomes 102, etc.


Your ultimate solution depends on how you are using the database.  If it is just a tool you are using to analyze data, run reports, scrub data, etc., adding another field and creating an update query whenever you add data should work.  If you are using Access to make an application that others will use, you can do the same principle but extra care may be needed so users never know what's happening behind the scenes.  But changing the data, if possible, makes everything else go away.
EDIT 1
Here is a simple query that should help you.  Just switch your query from design view to SQL View to see the queries (you can switch back design view then if you want).
Initial Sample Data:



ID
PartNum




1
R01


2
R10


3
R02


4
R30


5
R104


6
R01


7
R05


8
R34


9
R50



Running this query:
SELECT Products.ID, Products.PartNum
FROM Products
ORDER BY Products.PartNum;

Yields:



ID
PartNum




1
R01


6
R01


3
R02


7
R05


2
R10


5
R104


4
R30


8
R34


9
R50



And running this query:
SELECT Products.ID, Products.PartNum, Val(Right([PartNum],Len([PartNum])-1)) AS Expr1
FROM Products
ORDER BY Val(Right([PartNum],Len([PartNum])-1));

Yields:



ID
PartNum




6
R01


1
R01


3
R02


7
R05


2
R10


4
R30


8
R34


9
R50


5
R104



It basically just strips out the number from the PartNum and then sorts by that column.
EDIT 2
Assuming that the field containing R01, R100, etc. is [RING #], just add this line to the end of your query before the semicolon at the end:
ORDER BY Val(Right([RING #],Len([RING #])-1));

It it is [KEY #], add this line instead (before the semicolon at the end):
ORDER BY Val(Right([KEY #],Len([KEY #])-1));

So your new query would look like this for [RING #]:
SELECT [KEY RINGS & X RINGS & RESTRICT].[KEY #], [KEY RINGS & X RINGS & RESTRICT].[RING #], [KEY RINGS & X RINGS & RESTRICT].MAKE, [KEY RINGS & X RINGS & RESTRICT].[ASSIGNED AREA], [KEY RINGS & X RINGS & RESTRICT].LOCATION, [KEY RINGS & X RINGS & RESTRICT].[BOARD #], [KEY RINGS & X RINGS & RESTRICT].[MASTER #], [KEY RINGS & X RINGS & RESTRICT].ARSENAL AS Expr1, [KEY RINGS & X RINGS & RESTRICT].CAN AS Expr2
FROM [KEY RINGS & X RINGS & RESTRICT]
ORDER BY Val(Right([RING #],Len([RING #])-1));

EDIT 3
This query works for me, so there must be something different about our two systems.  Here is a screenshot of what the query looks like on my side.

And here is the data it produces, sorted correctly.

If this still doesn't work for you, please export a very small dataset (<= 5 records) to csv and post that here.  I can then import that and see where we differ.  Here is my dataset:
"KEY #","RING #","MAKE","ASSIGNED AREA","LOCATION","BOARD #","MASTER #","Expr1","Expr2"
,"R01",,,,,,,
,"R10",,,,,,,
,"R02",,,,,,,
,"R30",,,,,,,
,"R104",,,,,,,
,"R01",,,,,,,
,"R05",,,,,,,
,"R34",,,,,,,
,"R50",,,,,,,

I also recommend that you create a new query for this test to make sure you are not inheriting some issues from your current layout.

I am using it to run reports and keep records which I use to print out forms

Are you able to change the R01 to R001?  Or is that outside of your control?  If you can change it, I would do option 1.  If not, option 2.  Do both of those choices make sense, or do you need more clarification?

Not a option they all have to stay exactly as they are

Did the edited solution work for you?  If not, how can I clarify to make it work for you?

No is there a solution without the ID bing part of it? this is the set up now SELECT [KEY RINGS &  X RINGS & RESTRICT].[KEY #], [KEY RINGS &  X RINGS & RESTRICT].[RING #], [KEY RINGS &  X RINGS & RESTRICT].MAKE, [KEY RINGS &  X RINGS & RESTRICT].[ASSIGNED AREA], [KEY RINGS &  X RINGS & RESTRICT].LOCATION, [KEY RINGS &  X RINGS & RESTRICT].[BOARD #], [KEY RINGS &  X RINGS & RESTRICT].[MASTER #], [KEY RINGS &  X RINGS & RESTRICT].ARSENAL AS Expr1, [KEY RINGS &  X RINGS & RESTRICT].CAN AS Expr2
FROM [KEY RINGS &  X RINGS & RESTRICT];

Ok, Edit 2 should do the trick.  How did it work?

Still the same outcome I did try that one

Which field has the R01, R100, etc. in it?

Ring is the column

Edit 3 now published.  I have included images of the query and my sample dataset.  If this doesn't work, please post a very small version of your dataset. We are close to a solution I think.

Was that enough info to get you to the solution?  If not, let me know.
